# How can I hide FAB button while playing video fullscreen?

Tags: android, webview, floating-action-button

How to hide fab button while i play video in fullscreen? Show button until video goes fullscreen. I have a webview app with fab button.

Comment: find you fab button by id and set its visibitlity to false? it would be easier if you added any code snippets...

Comment: I want to show the button until the video goes full screen. Hide when double tapped in video(fullscreen)

Answer (score 0):

Find you FAB by `id` then just set visibility to false.

`myFAB.setVisibility(false)`

Answer (score 0):

`fab.setVisibility()` (mentioned in another answer) works fine for making the button simply disappear, but if you want if you want the button to animate it would be better to use [`fab.hide()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#hide()) and [`fab.show()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#show()) instead.